# Know the X know the man

Tags: phrase-requests

I've heard the phrase 'know the X, know the man' where X is some defining characteristic of the person. But now I can't find any external examples.

What's the original phrase?

(Side note, it may be knoweth the X, knoweth the man)

---

Using "Know the * know the man" in Google provides some examples:

- "know the golfer, know the man" - http://www.hourdetroit.com/Hour-Detroit/October-2013/Navigating-Troubled-Waters/
- "know the money, know the man" - http://people.com/tv/real-housewives-of-miami-premiere-alex-mccord-blogs
- "Know the material, know the man" - http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=621999

and mentioned in the comments:

- "Know the garbage, know the man" from Brooklyn 99 (although this is clearly stated as 'not a real saying').

Comment: Googling for the phrase (with quotes) "know the * know the man" (google uses the asterisk as a placeholder) pulls back various forms of the phrase. The best lead I can find is apparently from Brooklyn 99 s3e7 which apparently contains the line: "you know the old saying, 'know the garbage, know the man'". But I can't find a reference to that saying outside of that series. However it might provide a starting point. I've also found "Know the pot, know the man" ascribed as an old potters adage, but no other references than a single mention on a Daily Record news story.

Comment: The `*` raises some interesting results. I've been able to find a lot more examples of this, but it's quite possible they all come from a misremembering of 'cometh the hour, cometh the man'.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of the phrase **[cometh the hour, cometh the man](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/English_proverbs_(alphabetically_by_proverb)#C)**:

> Meaning: The biggest challenges in life brings out the best in people, as they rise to face the adversity.

<sup>wikiquote.com</sup>

This clearly has a different meaning to your phrase, but as googling your phrase mainly gives results for "I don't know the man", I suspect your memory has put the wrong verb in the phrase.

Comment: This is quite possible, I'll leave it a day but if no-one else knows I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley - I feel sure there is a phrase that has a closer meaning to what you've written, but I can't put my finger on it! I'll keep thinking.